# How to get previous day data from database with a time interval in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I try this but it's not working

```
{
'conditions' => array('Graph.hid' => $hid, 'DATE(Graph.created) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)', 'Graph.number'=>2)
}
```

Actually needed the current time data of previous day.
Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: you could also use virtual fields here. would make it somewhat more cake-ish and you can also sort by this field then etc. so a win-win situation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's this what you're looking for: `'conditions' => array('Graph.hid' => $hid, 'Graph.created' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use BETWEEN in your query (find) like this if you have DATETIME :

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", (time()-86400));
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE registration between '."'$yesterday 00:00:00'".' and '. "'$yesterday 23:59:59'";
```

between in cake is :

```
array('Post.read_count BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array(1,10))
```

other ways to calculate the last day :

```
date("Y-m-d", time() - 86400);
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday")); 
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));
```